# How to use a string and a variable in a gnuplot label in epslatex terminal?

Tags: gnuplot

Is it possible to use a self defined variable and a string in gnuplot label in epslatex terminal?
I want a label which says: " t85 = 15.6 ", where " t85 = " is the string and " 15.6 " is a variable I set in my gnuplot script.

```
set terminal epslatex
set output 'TP_MAG_5s_Decklage1.tex'
set xlabel "time / s"
set xrange [0:250]
set ylabel "T / C"
set yrange [0:1800]
TP_MAG_5s_Decklage1.dat"
t85_1 = system("awk '$1<800 && $1>500 { count++ } END { print count/100 }' TP_MAG_5s_Decklage1.dat")
t85_2 = system("awk '$2<800 && $2>500 { count++ } END { print count/100 }' TP_MAG_5s_Decklage1.dat")
set label 1 at 150,700 t85_1 
set label 2 at 150,600 t85_2 
plot 'TP_MAG_5s_Decklage1.dat' using ($0/100):1 w l title 'TC 1',\
     'TP_MAG_5s_Decklage1.dat' using ($0/100):2 w l title 'TC 2',\
      800 notitle , 500 notitle
```

This code gives me only the value of the variable as label. I am not able to add some text to this label.

Comment: This error usually happens when there is a missing closing `$` or when some text should be in math mode `$text$` and it isn't.

Comment: thanks, i found that missing $ sign, but I want to use Latex commands in the label ( I changed the example code to show the poblem)

Comment: You need the gprintf to display the variable name, and you could write the $ within the quotes, so it would be interpreted by LaTeX.

Comment: thanks, that solved it

Comment: I am glad it got solved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to my problem was to set the label like this:

```
set label 1 at 150,700 gprintf("$t_{8/5}$ = %.2f s",t85_1)
```

This way I can use the Latex Math Mode and call a variable.

Answer (score 0):

When you're using the `epslatex` terminal, you gnuplot script should produce two files: one `.eps` with the plot itself, and a `.tex` with all the labels. So if you open only the `.eps` file, you will not see the labels. Assuming your script produces `plot.tex` and `plot.eps`, running the following will produce a `myfile.pdf` file with all the labels in there:

```
#!/bin/bash    

cat << EOF > myfile.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\begin{document}
\input{plot}
\end{document}
EOF

pdflatex  myfile
```

Hopefully that will fix your issue. Also look at [this link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58900/gnuplot-epslatex-terminal-not-showing-axis-text).